# How I can find username and password fields in Chrome using Accessibility Service in android

Tags: android, google-chrome, passwords

I'm developing a Password Manager App, and I need to detect login page and username and password fields in Chrome (or other browsers) to paste in it values.
With searching nodes, I can list all the `EditText` there are in root:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)
{
    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = getRootInActiveWindow();

    if (source == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < source.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        AccessibilityNodeInfo node = source.getChild(i);

        if (node == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, node.getClassName().toString());

        // If it is a `EditText`, add it to a ArrayList, and ...

        if (node.getChildCount() > 0)
        {
            findFields(node);
        }
    }
}
```

But how I can understand that which `EditText` node is Username field and which `EditText` node is Password field?